# Apache directory issue which redirects request to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla

I have a joomla website.

In my public_html where Joomla is installed, I have a directory named "logs-list".

When I go to the address http://example.com/logs-list/file.txt, I expect the file to be shown, but instead APACHE redirects to index.php, it assumes as if this is a request for Joomla. This has confused me. What should I do?

**UPDATE**
how I can tell in `.htaccess` to stick to the physical directory for a certain URL?

Comment: Is `/logs-list/file.txt` a physical file?

Comment: Yes, it exists there.

Comment: You need to prevent this URL from triggering the URL rewriting. So in the .htaccess file that is in the root directory, search for "RewriteEngine On" and add to your question the lines under this that relate to the URL rewriting.

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess?

Comment: It is joomla's default `.htaccess`

Comment: FYI for anyone wanting to assist here... https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

Comment: Then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will allow access of all files

Comment: please see the updated question